# How to view an ASP.NET MVC mobile page on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

I have an open source ASP.NET MVC([nopcommerce](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/)) or nopcommerce.com it is developed in ASP.NET MVC and razor view, it is both desktop and mobile version for example it has index.cshtml and Index.Mobile.cshtml but I have no experience on mobile viewing,

I do highly appreciate if someone give a a clue on how to view mobile pages on the browsers like Chrome and IE.

Comment: With Safari you can `Develop > User Agent > iPhone` etc. You can also specify a custom user agent string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC you would declare [display-modes](http://theshravan.net/display-modes-in-asp-net-mvc-4/)

For example in the link above they declare a mode called WP, to access that mode you would have a `index.cshtml` (normal mode) and a `index.wp.cshtml` (detected mode)

Once you got that, you can set up all the modes you like by testing pretty much anything you like

For example my /APP_Start/DisplayModeConfig.cs

```
public class DisplayModeConfig
{
    public static void RegisterDisplayModes(DisplayModeProvider provider)
    {
        // INFO: Allows to name views/partials/masters like viewname.iphone.cshtml, and MVC will choose this automatically

        // INFO: Lets remove the default "Mobile" mode, since it's pretty useless
        var mobileDefault = DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.First(m => m.DisplayModeId == "Mobile");
        if (mobileDefault != null)
        {
            DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Remove(mobileDefault);
        }

        // INFO: Now add one that actually works
        provider.Modes.Insert(0,
            new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()) && Regex.IsMatch(context.GetOverriddenUserAgent(), @"mobile|android|kindle|silk|midp", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)))
            });


        // INFO: Order from least to most important (since we insert at position 0)
        provider.Modes.Insert(1,
            new DefaultDisplayMode("Win8")
            {
                ContextCondition = (context => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()) && context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf("Windows NT 6.2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
            });
    }
}
```

You also have a bunch of goodies in @Request.Browser.* like @Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice, @Request.Browser.Version,  ..most work fine, but i would test those helpers before relying on them.

Comment: That said, don't go crazy on displaymodes just because you can. For simple css/js stuff, stick with feature detections. DisplayModes should only be used when you need to switch out a whole page, or a rather large part of a page. For example a partial view with a fancy slider for Chrome, and a more compatible one for IE, where the JS, CSS, and HTML would be completely different. For adjusting design look at responsive design and @media-queries

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how mobile detection done by the site you may need:

- tweak "user agent" string coming from browser. There are many tools/plugins for that.
- set some sort of cookies
- see if "use mobile view" supported directly on the site (i.e. http://www.xbox.com have such link at the bottom).